# (60) Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user: Linux/Apache

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, https

I am trying to find out why my HTTPS link is not working for my website:

[image: broken https:// link]

So I ran this command to try:

```
curl https://localhost/
```

I am using a valid signed SSL certificate and my HTTP link is working fine. I am using a Multi Domain certificate that was exported from an IIS 6 server. My instance on AWS has the 443 port enabled.

Here is a picture of my CA certificates:
[image]

I have tried to change the http.conf file's Virtual Host following the instructions in here: http://ananthakrishnanravi.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/configuring-ssl-and-https-for-your-website-amazon-ec2/

Is there any suggestions on how to get my website properly working on a HTTPS protocol?

Let me know if you need anymore information.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

If you're not sure of the certificate that your web server is serving, you can use this command to view the certificate:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect hostname.domain.tld:443
```

Also, the hostname in the certificate must match the site that you are requesting.  For example, if you request a page from localhost, but your certificate is for www.yourdomain.com, the certificate check will fail.

Comment: My certificate has a SAN but it doesn't seem to be listed when inputting the command. I get this when I input name of the site, name.site.edu: No client certificate CA names sent ---SSL handshake has read 2708 bytes and written 561 bytes---New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is RC4-SHA Server public key is 2048 bit Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported. When I input site.edu I get this: No client certificate CA names sent ---SSL handshake has read 3952 bytes and written 561 bytes--- New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is RC4-SHA Server public key is 2048 bit Secure Renegotiation IS supported.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Self Signed SSL certificate then you faced this issue.

For this you can use curl command with -k option.

```sh
curl -k https://yourdomain.com/
```

And if you are trying with Postman that time disable the SSL Certificate option in setting.

Comment: this worked in linux bash when you using self-signed certificate

Answer (score 1):

This means that you are using a self-signed certificate.

In order for this warning not to appear, you need to purchase a certificate from a Certificate Authority.

Comment: I believe this was purchased from a CA Authority. In my PKCS#7 I can see that my certificate was issued by AddTrust External CA Root and InCommon Server CA.

Answer (score 0):

I got a same error but not similar to your, but summary here hope useful for others:

- OS: CentOS 7
- Run Python's `pyspider` error:

> File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
>
> raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
>
> File "", line 4, in raise_exc_info
>
> Exception: HTTP 599: Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.

- root cause and steps to fix:

previously existed a soft link:

`/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 -> /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4.3.0_openssl`

which is invalid one, so changed to valid:

`/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 -> /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4.3.0`

while two file is:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 435192 Nov  5  2018 /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4.3.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 399304 May 10 09:20 /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4.3.0_openssl
```

then for `pyspider` **reinstall pycurl**:

```
pip3 uninstall pycurl
export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=nss
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib;export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include;pip install pycurl --compile --no-cache-dir
```

in which `PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY` is `nss`, due to current `curl` backend is `nss` according to

```
# curl --version
curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.36 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3
...
```

can fix my problem.